# reading repeat xml using xmlnode

Tags: c#, xmlnode

I Have XML like

```
<rss>
<channel>
    <item>
        <category domain="category" nicename="change"><![CDATA[Changing Lives]]></category>
        <category domain="category" nicename="events"><![CDATA[Events]]></category>
        <category domain="category" nicename="leadership"><![CDATA[Leadership]]></category>
        <category domain="category" nicename="spiritual-transformation"><![CDATA[Spiritual Transformation]]></category>
    </item>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I am trying to read category innertext(changing lives, Events, Leadership) ... using foreach condition.. but for every loop I am getting Changing Lives only.. here is my code

```
    protected void btnImportPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    string strPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/willowcreekassociationblog.wordpress.xml");
    doc.Load(strPath);
    //Get Channel Node
    XmlNode channelNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("rss/channel");
    if (channelNode != null)
    {
        DateTime temp;
        //Add NameSpace
        XmlNamespaceManager nameSpace = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        nameSpace.AddNamespace("excerpt", "http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/excerpt/");
        nameSpace.AddNamespace("content", "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/");
        nameSpace.AddNamespace("dc", "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/");
        nameSpace.AddNamespace("wfw", "http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/");
        nameSpace.AddNamespace("wp", "http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/");

        //Parse each item
        foreach (XmlNode itemNode in channelNode.SelectNodes("item"))
        {
            //some code here

            foreach (XmlNode categoryNode in itemNode.SelectNodes("category"))
            {
                //CMS.SiteProvider.CategoryInfo GetCate = null;
                string CategoryName = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("category").InnerText;
                Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('root Document:" + CategoryName + "');</script>");

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you *have* to use `XmlDocument`? Using LINQ to XML would make all of this a lot simpler...

Comment: but this is already existing code..if change to xmldocument..i need to change lot of code... so i dont wanna do that..can we achieve this using cmlnode...

Comment: I'm sure it's feasible, but I don't have time to go back to the horrible .NET 2 XML API at the moment. Any effort spent refactoring to use LINQ to XML instead is likely to pay itself back really quickly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
string CategoryName = categoryNode.InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are not writing out the InnerText of itemNode each time round the loop, instead, you are using SelectSingleNode to pull out the first match only.

Try changing your inner loop to:

```
foreach (XmlNode categoryNode in itemNode.SelectNodes("category"))
{
   //CMS.SiteProvider.CategoryInfo GetCate = null;

   //string CategoryName = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("category").InnerText; // incorrect
   string CategoryName = categoryNode.InnerText;
   Console.Write(CategoryName);
}
```